# Unable to access S3 from CLI due to corporate proxy

Tags: command-line, amazon-s3, proxy, pip, aws-cli

I am trying to download data from my S3 bucket using AWS CLI.
The corporate proxy does not allow me to download data.
The request either gets timed out or fetches a connection error

Tried setting up the environment variables HTTP_PROXY and HTTPS_PROXY but it doesn't work.

(P.S: I gotta know that it is the Proxy issue by trying to download something else using pip.)

```
pip install -U boto
```

Also tried just pinging into the Python website(https) but it gives an error saying Ping request could not find host.

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: Did you successfully install the aws-cli package? Could you please provide a sample of the error you are experiencing?

Answer (score 3):

I installed [AWS CLI](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/userguide/cli-chap-welcome.html) in my Debian 8 machine that is sitting inside the corporate network.
For me, setting HTTP_PROXY variable did not work, but setting the `HTTPS_PROXY` variable worked:

`export HTTPS_PROXY=<Proxy IP>:<Proxy Port>`

After setting `HTTPS_PROXY` like shown above, my `aws configure` command went through without any issues.

If setting `HTTPS_PROXY` does not work for you, try configuring [Cntlm](http://cntlm.sourceforge.net/) as a "proxy to proxy" and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

```
pip install -U boto --proxy="proxyhost:port"
```